# How to make reference to a parent object property in the cloned object in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, oop, object, php-5.3

I want to do this:

```
class T
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = new P;
        $this->b = clone $this->a;
    }
}

class P
{
    public $name ="Chandler";
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->name = & $that->name;
    }

}

$tour = new T;
$tour->a->name = "Muriel";

?>
```

But after this, `$tour->b->name` will be `NULL`, why ?
How can I make the clone `name` property reference to the parent object `name` property, so when I change the parent object `name`, the cloned object `name` will change accordingly ?

Comment: OMG, I read in a book (Advanced PHP programming) that it refers to the object you want to clone, but it doesn't ! (At least in PHP 5.3.6) That's why it is NULL ! Thanks ! :D
Any idea if it was a feature in a earlier PHP version ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$that` doesn't exist in the `__clone` function as said in George Schlossnagle: Advanced PHP Programming book... It gave me a couple of weeks headache...
So, you can do this with a simple trick in the constructor (in class `P`); make the variable reference to himself:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->name = & $this->name;
}
```

this works in PHP 5.3.6. I did not test it in other versions.
So when you do `$tour->a->name = "Muriel";`, then `$tour->b->name` will be "Muriel" too!

Answer (score 1):

From the php.net cloning [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php),

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of
>   the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other
>   variables, will remain references.

but `$name` is a scalar variable (a string) and not an object. So when you clone `$a` to `$b`, `$a->name` and `$b->name` are distinct variables. ie) `$b->name` does not reference `$a->name`

In short, I do not believe that it is possible (please correct me if I am wrong). However, you could cheat and do something like:

```
class P
{
    public $name;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->name = new StdClass();
        $this->name->text = 'Chandler';
    }   
}
```

Then `$a->name->text = 'Muriel';` will also change `$b->name->text`.